# Text Appearing as Boxex [], "not in chrome", on right click, control panel, office,....many placeses

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, unicode

[image]

**Text Appearing as Boxex [], "not in chrome",  on right click, control panel, office,....many placeses**

i read out other similar question but didn't find help full, i just want US English language

Comment: run **sfc /scannow** to detect corrupted fonts and hope that Windows can restore the file.

Comment: Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them. Detailsare included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs|CBS.log

It Worked
"Thanks for the quick solution"

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that you can accept it, to "close" the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like some files/fonts are damaged. To repair broken files, open a [command prompt (cmd.exe) as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) and run [sfc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833):

[image]